# Is there a way to store the index range of a list directly?

Tags: python

If we do

```
>>> x = range(10)
```

then

```
>>> x[2:6]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I wonder if there a way can do something like

```
b=2:6
```

so that

```
x[b]
```

prints

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

```
b = slice(2,6)

x[b]
# [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This is equivalent to `x[2:6]`.

You can also pass a step parameter to slice, for instance:

```
b = slice(2,6,2)

x[b]
# [2, 4]
```

Which is the same as `x[2:6:2]`.